# HTML5 for Eclipse

Tags: html

I'm using php eclipse to create web pages, with which i can select different templates as i wish for ma coding purposes. But i the case for html files, i'm shown the templates upto html 4.1 and xhtml1.0 only. I can't find any html 5 templates there. I need to code in html 5. The absence of the template is causing the ide to show warnings and errors to the new tags as well as ignoring the depreciated tags. I need to build a site that is  strictly following html 5, i tried updating the eclipse, but for no use (atleast in this matter). What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is not a template per se, but a new set of validation rules. I know of no such rules at the moment and would suggest simply turning HTML error checking off.

Answer (score 0):

You need the newest release, and to have the HTML5 DOCTYPE declaration at the top of your file.